# Lua code elseif not working

Tags: lua, lua-5.3

This is all about accepting input from user and searching with that particular text.

Playing with `string.gsub`.

```
io.write("ENTER ANY STORY :-D ")
story=io.read()
io.write("\t OKAY!, THAT'S NICE :-D  ")
io.write("\t DO YOU WANT TO REPLACE ANY TEXT:?  ")
accept=io.read()
if accept=="YES" or "yes" then
  io.write("\t WHICH TEXT TO REPLAE?  ")
  replace=io.read()
  --HERE IS THE REPLACING TEXT
  io.write("\t WITH WHAT:?   ")
  with=io.read()
  result=string.gsub(story,replace,with)
  print("\t THE REPLACED TEXT IS: ",result)
elseif accept=="NO" or "no" then
  print(result)
end
```

Bug: The `elseif` loop isn't working!!

Comment: `accept=="YES" or "yes"` is not a correct way to implement the logic you want

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: `accept:upper()=="YES"`

Comment: Ok. The code worked. But I already added if accept==YES or yes . Which means any of those. Small or cap. Why isn't this running with that?

Answer (score 1):

`==` and `or` work like mathematical operators in that they are evaluated one at a time, with the `==` being evaluated first. If `accept` is `'no'`, `accept=="YES" or "yes"` will be evaluated like this:

```
(accept == "YES") or "yes"
('no' == "YES") or "yes"
false or "yes"
"yes"
```

In Lua, all values except `nil` and `false` are truthy, so your `if` block will always run instead of your `elseif` block.

As said in the comments, `accept:upper()=="YES"` will fix it. `accept:upper()` returns a string where all the letters of `accept` are converted to upper case, so then you only have to compare it to one value.

Comment: When i wanted to accept input from user in number I always needs to add ("*n")? accept=io.read("*n") why?

Comment: That's getting into stuff that's unrelated to the current question. The doc for `io.read` is [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:read). Depending on how much Lua you already know, I recommend searching for a Lua tutorial. Then look up stuff in the [Lua docs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/) for stuff you're not sure about. If you're still having trouble after that, you can ask another question.

Comment: Anyway,thanks a lot LUTHER. Your answer helped a lot!

Comment: In case it's not obvious, you'll have the same problem with `accept=="NO" or "no"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
io.write("ENTER ANY STORY :-D ")
story=io.read()
io.write("\t OKAY!, THAT'S NICE :-D  ")
io.write("\t DO YOU WANT TO REPLACE ANY TEXT:?  ")
accept=io.read()
if accept=="YES" or accept == "yes" then
  io.write("\t WHICH TEXT TO REPLAE?  ")
  replace=io.read()
  --HERE IS THE REPLACING TEXT
  io.write("\t WITH WHAT:?   ")
  with=io.read()
  result=string.gsub(story,replace,with)
  print("\t THE REPLACED TEXT IS: ",result)
elseif accept=="NO" or accept == "no" then
  print(result)
end
```